# Create PDF from HTML with vertical text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am creating a PDF using iTextSharp 5.4.5 in .NET 4.0 like this:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            string html="<span style='transform: rotate(-90deg)'>Some Text</span>";
            byte[] file=PDFGenerator.GeneratePDF(html);
            string filename=@"C:\Users\myaccount\Desktop\myfile.pdf";
            var v=System.IO.File.Create(filename);
            v.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
            }
}
public class PDFGenerator
        {
        public static byte[] GeneratePDF(string html)
            {
            MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
            TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput);
            HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            document.Open();
            worker.StartDocument();
            worker.Parse(reader);
            worker.EndDocument();
            worker.Close();
            document.Close();
            return msOutput.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

However, the text in the PDF is not coming out rotated at all. I need the text to be rotated vertically. Is there any CSS or HTML I can enter so that it will rotate?

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLWorker` has been deprecated for a very long time in favor of `XMLWorker` and zero work is being done in it. The former doesn't really support CSS while the latter does, too. However, the `transform` CSS property isn't supported anyway so that doesn't help you. ([See this for a list of supported properties](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm).)

Do you have an absolute need for HTML parsing? If not, you can just use the `ColumnText` class to do what you want. PDFs origins are in the bottom left corner instead of the top left so might need to adjust your math. Also, rotations are in the opposite direction so your `-90` becomes just `90`.

```
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("Hello World"), 50, 50, 90);
```

Comment: The document does have to be generated from HTML. However it looks like short of modifying iTextSharp, it would just be impossible to accomplish what I want.